# How to design a comparator using op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, hysteresis

Intention is to design a comparator with following specification:

Input: 0V to 1.65V, Output: Low

Input: 2.1V to 5V, Output: High

[This](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu020a/tidu020a.pdf) is the TI design doc I have refereed for the design.

Please see the circuit diagram for your reference:
(Highlighted in green rectangle)
[image]

For my design requirement, I have recalculated the value of Rx, Ry and Rh as follows,

Rx = 10K
Ry = 5.689K
Rh = 36.67K
( VL = 1.65V, VH= 2.1V and VCC = 5V)

Formulas used are also from the [TI doc](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu020a/tidu020a.pdf)
[image]

But the simulation result is as follows:

[image]

[image]

Obs: As per the LTSpice simulation VL is 2.02V and VH is 1.65V
It is not matching with the design I have done.

Please do advice why there is a mismatch between the design and simulation. Kindly let me know if further any information required.

Comment: Can you label the nodes in your circuit so we can tell which trace in the chart is which?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assuming the op-amp will output 5V when high and 0V when low, they do not.

Look at the green output in your image, notice high is under 4.5V and low is above ground.

You would need to use those voltages in your math.

[image]

Also be aware, Voh and Vol of the op-amp will vary from device to device, with temperature, and depending on what load is attached to the output. Using op-amps as comparators is generally not a great idea.

**ADDITION:**

The above is partly the reason why most actual comparator devices are open collector outputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPGyhj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$Th_{lo} \approx  V_{cc} * R2||R3/(R1 + R2||R3)\$

\$Th_{hi} = V_{cc} * R2/(R2 + R1||(R3+R4))\$

Comment: Ideally it should be 5V high and 0V low right? Why this change?
 How can I make 5V high and 0V low at output?

Comment: @vt673 you can pick a better op-amp that gets closer to the rail, but you will never get  exactly 5V and 0V. You need to figure out how much tolerance you can accept on the thresholds and work it back from there.

Comment: I was referring the op-omp datasheet,[link](http://www.linear.com/docs/1414). I am bit confused as I failed to find the tolerance of LT1006. What parameter can be referred against the the change in high and low of the op-amp output?

Comment: @vt673 Maximum Output Voltage Swing.. at 5V ~ 4.4V typical. Can be as low as 4V could be closer to 5V..